# deleting pivot field from pivot table field list in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

Is it possible to delete pivot field from pivot table field list in VBA code?

I am using Excel 2007.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked for a long time with Excel + VBA, but have you tried something like:

```
Dim pvtField As Excel.PivotField
Dim pvtItem As Excel.PivotItem
For Each pvtField In pvtTable.PivotFields 
    For Each pvtItem In pvtField.PivotItems 
        pvtItem.Delete 
    Next 
Next
```

Comment: I dont want to delete the items..i want to delete the field itself

Comment: Ah, ok. Then I can not help, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

This code should work to delete a field from the pivot table.

```
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Name of Table").PivotFields( _
    "Name of Field").Orientation = xlHidden
```